# How to create Google calendar link date in Javascript 2022?

Tags: javascript

In 2022 the create Google calendar event link looks like this:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?sf=true&output=xml&text=sometext&location=somelocation&details=somedetails&dates=20220418T013000Z/20220416T020000Z
```

How do you formate such date in Javascript?

```
const formatDate = (date) => {
 ???
};
const myDate = new Date();
const myFormattedDate = formatDate(myDate);
console.log(myFormattedDate)
```

expecting output:

```
20220418T013000Z
```

Any nice looking and easy solution (rather than `getHours(),getMinutes()`,etc.)?

Comment: 20220418T013000Z you just need to filter it out from the parameter of that link. You can do this by using Regex.

Comment: @ash Not sure that’s what the OP is asking - it’s clear they’re looking for a solution to generate these dates, not extract/parse them.

Comment: @esqew sorry sir I am just a kind of new developer and in social media too. Just trying to redirect things. By the way, you have a Good profile.

Comment: “*Any nice looking and easy solution*” Can you elaborate on the reason for this rather arbitrary requirement? It seems that the methods you describe would be exactly what you’re after - just concatenate their outputs together in the proper order/template string and you’d have what you want.

Comment: @esqew you can do this  I am waiting for the solution

Comment: Just one notice for further readers, if you go with `getHours(),getMinutes()` approach don't forget to shift the date with timezone diff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JS Dates have an inbuilt .toISOString() method which gets the right format, then just remove special characters:

```js
  let date = new Date();
  let isoDate = date.toISOString()
  let formattedDate = isoDate.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');

  console.log(formattedDate)
```